# When $mB \neq B$? $m$ is a maximal ideal of $A$, $A \subseteq B$

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, abstract-algebra, flatness

The following is a question I have asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1381867/when-mb-neq-b-m-is-a-maximal-ideal-of-a-a-subseteq-b) without receiving any comments, therefore I post it here:

Let $A \subseteq B$ be commutative rings, $m$ a maximal ideal of $A$.
When $mB \neq B$?

This is true when $A \subseteq B$ is faithfully flat.
(If I am not wrong, this is also true when $A \subseteq B$ is integral).
Any other ideas are welcome.

Please notice: A similar (but not identical, I think) question is:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194261/when-does-mathfrakab-cap-a-mathfraka/194306#194306, since the property I am talking about is slightly more general then $IB \cap A =I$, for every ideal $I$ of $A$.
Indeed, let $m$ be a maximal ideal of $A$. Then, in particular,  $mB \cap A=m$ and if $mB=B$ we would get $A= B \cap A = mB \cap A=m$, a contradiction to the maximality of $m$. So, "$IB \cap A =I$ implies $mB \neq B$".
(An exercise in Atiyah-MacDonald, which was mentioned in the second answer of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194261/when-does-mathfrakab-cap-a-mathfraka/194306#194306 shows that for a flat extension those two properties are equivalent).

Comment: Question is not so fundamental. Let A be ANY field, so m = 0 is its maximal ideal. And for any extension B, we have mB = 0.

Comment: Tautologically, your condition means that $m$ belongs to the image of the morphism $\mathrm{Spec}(B)\rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}(A)$. This morphism is surjective indeed if $B$ is faithfully flat or integral over $A$; it is not in other situations, e.g. if $B$ is a localization of $A$. I don't think you can say much more.

Comment: Thank you very much. Please, do you claim that TFAE: (1) $mB \neq B$ for every maximal ideal $m$ of $A$. (2) For every prime ideal $p$ of $A$ there exists a prime ideal $q$ of $B$ such that $p= q \cap A$.

Comment: No, I didn't say that.

Comment: Thanks. Did you mean: If $mB \neq B$, then there exists a prime ideal $q$ of $B$ such that $m=q \cap A$?

Comment: And please, how one shows that the above morphism is surjective ONLY for $A \subseteq B$ integral or faithfully flat?

Comment: I didn't say that either.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your comment (you can write it as an answer if you wish).

Comment: The first thing your question makes thinking  of , is Nakayama's Lamma ! It must give counterexamples . Am I wrong ?

Comment: Probably not, though I do not know how to construct an extension $A \subseteq B$ which is not f.f. not integral and satisfying $mB \neq B$, using Nakayama's Lemma. It would be nice if you will let me know when finding such. (BTW, I did not claim f.f. and integral are the only such extensions. Actually, I hoped there exist other examples and wanted to know if one can characterize all extensions $A \subseteq B$ with $mB \neq B$).

Comment: @abx Last try: Did you mean: If $m$ belongs to the image of the spectrum map, then $mB \neq B$. This claim I can prove: If $m$ is in the image, then $m=q \cap A$ for some prime ideal $q$ of $B$. Then, $mB=(q \cap A)B \subseteq qB \cap AB=q \cap B=q \neq B$.

Comment: In other words: If the (max)spectrum map is surjective, then $mB \neq B$ for every maximal ideal $m \in A$. So my condition ($mB \neq B$ for every maximal ideal $m \in A$) is weaker then surjectivity of the spectrum map. (Please, why did you say "tautologically ..." if the two conditions are not equivalent?).

Comment: The two conditions are equivalent when $A \subseteq B$ is flat (this appears in the above mentioned exercise of Atiyah-MacDonald).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few  comments that may help.

1. As abx explains, a good way to think about it is in terms whether or not $m$ lies in image of the map on spectra.
2. As you surmised, either condition of faithful flatness or integrality are sufficient,
3. but not necessary! For example, take $A=k[x,y]$ and  the affine blow up $B=k[x,y,z]/(y-zt)$. I'll let you convince yourself that it is surjective on spectra but neither flat nor integral (think about the fibres).

Comment: Thanks!! When I wrote "Any other ideas are welcome", I meant that I suspect there exist other cases (=not f.f. not integral) where $mB \neq B$; your nice example is (probably) one of them, so it may serve as an answer. However, it would be even nicer to know if one can characterize all (commutative) ring extensions $A \subseteq B$ such that $mB \neq B$. Namely, if one can say that faithfully flat, integral and ... are precisely the extensions that satisfy $mB \neq B$. That's what I originally tried to ask (and hoped there exists a paper on this question, which I am not aware of)

Answer (score -2):

This is a bit of a non-answer, but it doesn't fit in a comment, so I put it here. You write "If I am not wrong, this is also true when $A\subseteq B$ is integral".

I think you are mistaken here. Let $B = \mathbb{R}$ (which as a field is clearly an integral domain) and $A = \mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. This is a maximal ideal of $A = \mathbb{Z}$ (but of course it is not an ideal of $B=\mathbb{R}$ because $\mathbb{R}$ as a field doesn't have non-trivial ideals).

Let $m = 2\mathbb{Z}\subseteq A$. Then we have $\frac{1}{2}\in \mathbb{R}=B$ and therefore $\frac{1}{2}\cdot 2 = 1\in Bm = mB$ therefore $mB = B$.

Comment: I think you are confused about the meaning of "integral". It means that any element of $B$ is annihilated by a monic polynomial with coefficients in $A$. $\mathbb{R}$ is certainly not integral over $\mathbb{Z}$.